# R obtaining rownames date using quantmod

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Using quantmod and collecting data from Yahoo.
I am trying to get the dates that are in rownames.
However I am just getting NULL.

```
library("quantmod")
sp500 <- new.env()

getSymbols("^GSPC", env = sp500, src = "yahoo",
           from = as.Date("2008-01-04"),  to = Sys.Date())
GSPC <- get("GSPC", envir = sp500)
date1 <- rownames(GSPC)

date1
> NULL
```

I would be grateful for your help into getting the rowname dates into a vector.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the `index` function. The `xts` object isn't the same as a normal `data.frame`, and has its own way of handling dimension names.

```
# Return all dates
index(GSPC)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is broken, the way it was reported in your question.

```
sp500 <- new.env()

getSymbols("^GSPC", env = sp500, src = "yahoo",
    from = as.Date("2008-01-04"), to = Sys.Date()) 

GSPC <- get("GSPC", envir = sp500)
```

Then you can do `time(GSPC)`, which got a method for this kind of object.